# Repeater ItemCreated not being called on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, postback

Got a very "Schrodinger's Cat" moment going on right now.

First, some background on my setup. Most of this is probably irrelevant, but, for completeness, I'm providing it. I'm using a .NET 4.6.2 WebForm (.ASPX page) with a MasterPage. The MasterPage is contained within another MasterPage. Within the WebForm I have an UpdatePanel (UpdateMode = Conditional). Inside the UpdatePanel I have another UpdatePanel (also with UpdateMode = Conditional). Inside that inner UpdatePanel, I have a Repeater and a Button. The Repeater is bound during the Page_Load event of the WebForm, and within a !Page.IsPostBack block. The Button has a Click event that accesses the Repeater.Items Collection.

For some reason, when the Button is Clicked, on PostBack, if the Repeater.Controls Collection is accessed *at any time* before Page_Load, the Collection becomes emptied. I've tried to figure out at exactly what point the Collection is filled on PostBack, but it seems to be happening somewhere inside the System.Web.dll file, and I can't seem to debug inside that (an unrelated, but frustrating issue).

To simulate this, I've done the following:

1) Added an empty handler for the Repeater.ItemCreated event and put a breakpoint within this event

2) Put a breakpoint on the Page_Init event of the WebForm

3) Added a debugger watch for the Repeater.HasControls() method

When the page is first loaded and the Page_Init breakpoint is hit, the Repeater.HasControls() method properly evaluates as false. During the Page_Load event, since this is not a PostBack, the Repeater is bound, and the Repeater.ItemCreated and the Repeater.ItemDataBound events are fired once for each row created in the Repeater.

When the Button is clicked, a PostBack occurs. When the Page_Init breakpoint is hit, the Repeater.HasControls() method again evaluates as false. If I do nothing else, the next event that fires is the Repeater.ItemCreated event, once for each row - this time around, the Repeater.ItemDataBound event doesn't fire, which is normal, since the Repeater is not being rebound on PostBack (and, for that matter, we haven't reached the Page_Load event either way). Next, the Button Click event is evaluated, and it properly loops through the Repeater.Items Collection. All good.

**However**, if, during this Button Click PostBack Page Init event, instead of simply evaluating the Repeater.HasControls() method, I access the Repeater.Controls Collection - IE, I put a code block that checks Repeater.Controls, I put a watch on Repeater.Controls, or I even just do a quick watch on Repeater.Controls, **the Repeater.ItemCreated event no longer fires**. When the Button Click event is evaluated and it tries looping through the Repeater.Items Collection, the Collection is now empty.

I've tried everything I can think of to figure out why this is happening, and have had no success. If anyone has any suggestions on more things I can test for, places I can search, or whatever, I'd love some advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know that if you access the Controls property, it will call EnsureChildControls which I think will build the Repeater control hierarchy from ViewState.  Are you sure you aren't doing this before binding a handler to the `ItemCreated` event?  In any case it would be interesting to know exactly what you want to achieve: I suspect the Init event may not be the place to do it.

Comment: @Joe, my actual problem resides elsewhere, but for background, I'm accessing Repeater.Controls during the Page_Init event of the MasterPage, as part of a process that is setting page translations. The handler for ItemCreated is being bound on the control itself, IE, OnItemCreated=Repeater_ItemCreated - not for any actual usage, but just to help try and isolate the problem. I'm guessing, from what you've said, that it will only call the EnsureChildControls once - and that when its being called on my MasterPage Init event, the ViewState is empty. Is there any way to reset that flag after?

Comment: If you can describe what you are trying to achieve (perhaps in a separate question, ideally with an MVCE) I could maybe help.  As a rule you shouldn't access the Controls collection in Init.  If I understood right, and you want to translate properties you should only need to access properties of the Repeater itself and its templates.  EnsureChildControls can be called multiple times, but only creates the child controls the first time through.  For ViewState load to work, the control tree needs to be the same when LoadViewState is called on PostBack as it was when the ViewState was saved

Comment: @Joe that gives me some ideas to try out. I'll get back to you tomorrow after I've had a chance to experiment a bit. Thanks for the ideas!